# Why is trade openness positively correlated with economic prosperity?

Tags: macroeconomics, international-trade

Is there any confirmed saying on this problem?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_trade#Ricardian_model

Answer (score 1):

In short: Yes and due to comparative advantage.

The level of GDP growth gained with opening trade does vary by country and time. I'd suggest Wacziarg & Welch (2008). Trade Liberalization and Growth: New Evidence, World Bank Economic Review, vol. 22(2) for a relatively new study on the subject.